# Failure/Error: visit movie_url(movie) ActionView::Template::Error: wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, rspec-rails

This question sounds very similar to those that have already been asked and answered thought I can't seem to figure it out.

I have the following error message that makes my spec test fail.

```
Failures:

  1) Navigating movies allows navigation from the detail page to the listing page
     Failure/Error: visit movie_url(movie)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)
     # ./app/views/movies/show.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_movies_show_html_erb__1138068182152565203_70152862507580'
     # ./spec/navigate_movies_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.20747 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/navigate_movies_spec.rb:5 # Navigating movies allows navigation from the detail page to the listing page

Randomized with seed 14064
```

My actual spec test looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  describe "Navigating movies" do
    it "allows navigation from the detail page to the listing page" do
    ...
    visit movie_url(movie)

    click_link "All Movies"

    expect(current_path).to eq(movies_path)
  end
end
```

My show page:
         <%= link_to "All Movies", movies_path %>
Edited:

```
rake routes
Prefix Verb URI Pattern           Controller#Action
movies GET  /movies(.:format)     movies#index
 movie GET  /movies/:id(.:format) movies#show
```

Edit #3

```
bundle exec rspec -b
FF.

Failures:

  1) Viewing an individual movie shows the movie's details
     Failure/Error: visit movie_url(movie)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:150:in `url_for'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:280:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:223:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:345:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
     # ./app/views/movies/show.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_movies_show_html_erb__342552887677354596_70168586387480'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
     # /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:66:in `block in call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:30:in `request'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:244:in `process_request'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:58:in `get'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:59:in `process'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:35:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:21:in `visit'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:42:in `visit'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:193:in `visit'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/show_movie_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `instance_eval'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:114:in `block in run'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:179:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:179:in `run'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `instance_eval_with_args'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:87:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:89:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:89:in `run'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:418:in `run_hook'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:329:in `run_around_each_hooks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:256:in `with_around_each_hooks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:111:in `run'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:390:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `map'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:386:in `run_examples'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:371:in `run'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

  2) Navigating movies allows navigation from the detail page to the listing page
     Failure/Error: visit movie_url(movie.to_param)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:150:in `url_for'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:280:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:223:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:345:in `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
     # ./app/views/movies/show.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_movies_show_html_erb__342552887677354596_70168586387480'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
     # /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-
     # /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

Finished in 0.84651 seconds
3 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/show_movie_spec.rb:6 # Viewing an individual movie shows the movie's details
rspec ./spec/navigate_movies_spec.rb:5 # Navigating movies allows navigation from the detail page to the listing page
```

Comment: Is that really line 24 of app/views/movies/show.html.erb

Comment: @FrederickCheung line 24 is `<%= link_to "All Movies", movies_path %>`

Comment: Try running with `rspec -b` to get the full backtrace

Comment: @FrederickCheung I condensed the bottom of the trace because I went above the character limit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run rake routes and see how many parameters your movie_url can take? According to REST your url looks okey, but if you can make sure that there is no additional path which is overriding your current path thats fine.

Also can you try the following and see what happens?

```
movie_url({id: movie.to_param})
```

or

```
movie_url(movie.to_param)
```

Comment: updated the question with the routes. Assuming you mean add the above code to visit action i get the following for both.  `Failure/Error: visit movie_url({id: movie.to_param})
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..1)`

Comment: so now what I can prefer is an unusual debugging. Can you get install the pry gem and set it before your movie_url path? when you run the code you will prompt so than you can inspect every variable including your url helper. This can give you a lot of information why this issue is going on.

Comment: Not to familiar with debugging this way but I will look into it and check back in . Thanks.